# Auto rebuild docker container after code change

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm running two containers using `docker-compose`. Is there an option to force docker-compose to rebuild and to run the container after any code change? If so, I would like to get an example. If it isn't possible, is there a workaround for that case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there an option to force docker-compose to rebuild and to run the
>   container after any code change?

Docker doesn't have option to perform a watch files-rebuild process.

> If it isn't possible, is there a workaround for that case?

For applications running on Docker in a local environment, to achieve such a thing, I generally avoid full-packaging the applications.
Instead, I rely on the dev mode abilities of the applicative libraries/frameworks that I use.

The idea is to do a bind mount of the source code located in the host and to take advantage of auto-hot deploy feature provided by the dev mode of the libraries/frameworks that I use.
Nowadays, modern libraries/frameworks provide a dev mode for that.
For example Spring Boot applications allow that with the maven plugin (mvn `spring-boot:run`) and the devtools dependency, Angular applications allow that with `ng serve`, ...